# Filtering Arraylist

Tags: java

I have 2 array
 tickets and filterTickets
I want to return new tickets that does not contain member from filterTickets.
I use this code but filter not working.

```java
List < Ticket > a = new ArrayList <>();
for (String string: ticketsFilter) {
    for (Ticket ticket: tickets) {
        if (ticket.getTicketId().equals(string))
            a.add(ticket);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you wanted to add to `a` if it is *not* in the `ticketsFilter` list. Anyway, flip the two loops, then replace the inner loop with a call to `contains`. That would get you: `for (Ticket ticket : tickets) { if (! ticketsFilter.contains(ticket.getTicketId())) { a.add(ticket); } }` --- For better performance, `ticketsFilter` should be a `Set`, not a `List`.

Comment: I use not also but that return all of member without filter also

Comment: Java 8 way List<Ticket> filteredTickets = tickets.stream().filter(t -> ticketsFilter.stream().anyMatch(s-> s.equals(t.getTicketId())).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 3):

From your description , You should have a filterTickets which is a list of strings, then you can use the follow code to check if the filterTickets contains the ticketId:

```
 List<String> ticketsFilter = new ArrayList<>();
 ...
 if(!ticketsFilter.contains(ticket.getTicketId())){
     a.add(ticket);
 }
```

Comment: It's better to use `Set<String> ticketsFilter = new HashSet<>();`. `Set` serves `contains` algorithmically faster (constant time here) then any implementation of `List`.

Comment: could you please paste your code here or update in the question? it should work form my understanding of your question

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 solution using stream API:

```
List<Ticket> a = tickets.stream()
                .filter(e->!ticketsFilter.contains(e.getTicketId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: but is it support for API 19, because in android studio when I use it that information say Call API 24

Comment: @Andrinovariswanto Your question didn't even mention that this is for Android, so this answer is relevant to the question, as it currently stands.

Comment: Ahhhh, Thanks by the way dude